# rake db:create:all => FATAL: password authentication failed for user "foo"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rails-postgresql

Trying to setup a postgresql db for the first time. I'm using [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql/) railscast. After many hours of frustrating issues, I got as far as rake db:create:all. Now I get the error:

```
password authentication failed for user "pgtest"
```

Here is my pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Here is my database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: pgtest_development
  pool: 5
  username: pgtest
  password: password

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: pgtest_test
  pool: 5
  username: pgtest
  password: password
```

I tried it first with no password and it gives the error:

```
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks :)

Comment: your postgres password is not valid have you created pgtest user,try login with psql  or pgadmin3 for postgres and then check

Comment: I'm not sure if it's critical but you don't have a `host` in your database.yml configurations.

Comment: @ Amar, in pgadmin3 it says username 'postgres' so I changed pg_hba.conf to username postgres and the password next to it is the password for user postgres. AND IT WORKED! =)  But is that a problem making it user postgres? I thought that was like admin user or something. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you just wrote changes to your pg_hba.conf and didn't `RELOAD` or `RESTART` PostgreSQL do that first.  Those are common causes of what you describe.

If that didn't fix it, then you are either editing the wrong pg_hba.conf or you have rules specified earlier in the file that you aren't showing us.  Rule out those cases in that order.